# How can I access the Sitecore 9 configuration values programmatically?

Tags: configuration, site-configuration, settings

I'm trying to **get this given node value from the Sitecore configuration** (Sitecore 9 instance).

My first approach was to **read the configuration file** on which this value is defined. Pretty standard...

The issue is that I just realized that a customer can **add another configuration file to patch this value**, what would make my first approach return a wrong value.

What is the best way of reading the final computed Sitecore configuration (what we see in the `/showconfig.aspx`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After struggling with this for a while, finally found the answers.

If what you are trying to read is **really a setting** following the below format:

```
<setting name="THE_NAME_GOES_HERE" value="THE_VALUE_GOES_HERE" />
```

You can use the `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting(p_Name, p_DefaultValue)` method to read it.

However, if what you are trying to read a **Sitecore config node**, the above method won't work.

In this case, you should aim to use the `Factory.GetConfigNode(p_XmlPath)` method and then grab the node's value.

Comment: If you want a real mindbender, checkout the `SettingsSwitcher` which allows you to create a context that sets a value for a specific setting, regardless of the value in the config.

Comment: TIL that Pete, thanks a lot!